# "Hardcoded string xxx should use @string resource" issue

Tags: android

I'm getting the following error in hello world activity code:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
[I18N] Hardcoded string "and this is a clickable button!", 
    should use @string resource
activity_hello_world.xml/HelloWorld/res/layout line 21 Android Lint Problem
```

Please help me out.

Comment: This is just an warning , trying to bring your code to industry standard . Copy your hard coded string and paste it in file called String.xml .

Answer (score 18):

This is not an error, this is a Lint warning. So you can run the App, but the recommended way to display texts(on TextViews, Buttons etc.) is to use string references. You have to go to your res folder and there will be a strings.xml file under values. Add this in there:

```
   <string name="my_string">Your Text!</string>
```

And to set text on you button you then have to do this:

```
android:text="@string/my_string"
```

Comment: but i am not able to run the app still

Comment: The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project HelloWorld  Unknown Java Problem

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Unable to resolve target 'android-16' until the SDK is loaded. HelloWorld  Unknown Android Target Problem

Comment: @Ahmad I tried the same approach , but my button also show "@string/" on button , why is that

Answer (score 0):

example- (of keypad)

put this under file string.xml under values folder

```
<string name="keypad_title">Keypad</string>
```

put this code under keypad.xml  under  layout folder

```
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_1"
     android:text="1">
  </Button>
```